# convert POJO to JSON and add new key:value pairs to that JSON

Tags: java, json

I'm doing the POJO to JSON convertion like below. The same is working fine.

```
public class Pojo2Json {

    public static String pojo2Json(Object obj) throws JAXBException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
      return jsonString;
    }
```

Now the generated pojo doesn't give all the values required to pass in other API call. So I need to add some more key value pairs. I'm doing the same as below...

```
public static void insertValues(String jsonString) throws JSONException
   {
       JSONObject js = new JSONObject(jsonString);
       js.put("time", DateTime.now());
       js.put("node-level", "development");
   }
```

Now it's adding the key value pairs at the begining of the JSON. like... {"time":"2014-04-11T16:09:10.825+05:30","node-level":"development"...

I want this key values to be added at the bottom of existing JSON. Please let me know how to do so.

Thanks,
Bagui

Comment: have you looked at gson? https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Does order make any sense here. I don't think it matters in JSON as it can be converted to any object(JS) or JAVA POJO despite of order of the feild

Comment: @Sid some webservices do validation on order of elements inside json also

Comment: A JSON "object" is by definition unordered.  You can't control the order of the entries in it.  Any site that requires a certain order is broken.

Comment: @Sid - the order is needed as I'm pushing that json in NoSQL database.

Comment: can someone please suggest the solution here.